# zoom in/out messes up newsletter- How does zooming in/out affect the page?

Tags: html, css

I made a newsletter, but whenever I (or the client) zoom in or out it messes up the proportions. I wasn't able to fix it, nor find (enough) helpful information on how to solve this.

Here's an example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/nmK6R/

Try to play with the zoom (Ctrl -) to see what's wrong. notice the top left section:

[image: http://bit.ly/1cz47eX]

Notice that (at least in my PC) at 100% Zoom the proportions are great but either zoom in or out messes it up.

More than fixing the problem I would like to understand it better-
What is happening when I zoom in/out that makes the proportions change- why some elements change differently than others- I feel that if I truly understand how this works- more than fixing this mailer's problem i'll be able to this problem in further newsletters.

So Even if you won't solve this problem but explain me how zooming works- I might be able to solve it myself- it's just that I don't know what's happening so I don't know what's need to be fixed :p

I thank you for your help.

As requested, here's the (simplified ) code:

```
<table id="Table_01" width="872" height="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl" style="margin: auto;">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td>
        <img style="border:0; display:block;" src="http://newsletter.pwizard.com/upload/account_86/template/images/newslettter-boz-new3_01.jpg" width="871" height="39" alt="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody><tr> 
                <td bgcolor="f8ebbe">
                    <img width="61" style="border:0; display:block;" src="http://newsletter.pwizard.com/upload/pix.gif">
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="9e7641">
                    <img width="25" style="border:0; display:block;" src="http://newsletter.pwizard.com/upload/pix.gif">
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="f5f2e3">
                    <img width="23" style="border:0; display:block;" src="http://newsletter.pwizard.com/upload/pix.gif">
                <td bgcolor="red">
                    <img width="651" style="border:0; display:block;" src="http://newsletter.pwizard.com/upload/pix.gif">
                <td bgcolor="f5f2e3">
                    <img width="26" style="border:0; display:block;" src="http://newsletter.pwizard.com/upload/pix.gif">
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="9e7641">
                    <img width="27" style="border:0; display:block;" src="http://newsletter.pwizard.com/upload/pix.gif">
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="f8ebbe">
                    <img width="58" style="border:0; display:block;" src="http://newsletter.pwizard.com/upload/pix.gif">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody></table>
          </td>
        </tr> 

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks fine for me in Chrome on OS X. Can you post some code here and details (perhaps a screen shot) to show what exactly is wrong?

Comment: screen shot: http://bit.ly/1cz1GZS

As for the code- you can use developer tools at the link in the question.

Thank you.

Comment: Please check out [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Comment: There.. Now there's fiddle, code, small example. All but a solution :)